# node Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, pg, node-postgres

I use pool with transaction and I have a long function but if an error occurs I say

```
await client.query('ROLLBACK');
```

but after few minutes I get this:

```
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
```

Here is my code a little bit long but I show when an error occurs I every use rollback. What I am doing wrong ? Because the queries are not running when an error occurs I return and its end so why I get this error ?

```
  const client = await connectors['xxx'].connect();
  let kilometerPacket = 0;
  try {
    const d = await request.json() as {
      id: string;
      data: IPaymentData;
    };

    if(d.data.car && d.data.info && d.data.booking_info) {
 
      if(d.data.booking_info.start_date && d.data.booking_info.end_date && d.data.booking_info.location_id) {

        if(!isValidDate(new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.start_date))) && !isValidDate(new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.end_date)))) {
          return json({
            error: 'Datum ist ungültig.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        if(isNaN(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.location_id))) {
          return json({
            error: 'Location ungültig.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        if(!d.data.info.surname && !d.data.info.lastname && !d.data.info.email && !d.data.info.phone && !d.data.info.city &&
          !d.data.info.plz && !d.data.info.city && !d.data.info.plz && !d.data.info.day && !d.data.info.month && !d.data.info.year) {
          return json({
            error: 'Info ungültig.'
          }, {headers});
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        if(isNaN(parseInt(d.data.car.id))) {
          return json({
            error: 'Kein Fahrzeug ausgewählt.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        const getStationID = getStationByID({db_name: 'xxx', station_id: parseInt(d.data.booking_info.location_id)});
        // @ts-ignore
        const getCar = getCarByID({db_name: 'xxx', car_id: parseInt(d.data.car.id)});

        const queries = await Promise.all([getStationID, getCar]);

        const stationData = queries[0] as STATIONS;
        const carData = queries[1] as ICarById;

        if(!stationData && !carData) {
          return json({
            error: 'Etwas ist schief gelaufen. Probiere es erneut.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        if(!stationData?.station_id) {
          return json({
            error: 'Station existiert nicht.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        if(!carData?.id) {
          return json({
            error: 'Fahrzeug existiert nicht.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        if(stationData.station_id !== parseInt(d.data.booking_info.location_id)) {
          return json({
            error: 'Station ID stimmem nicht überein.'
          }, {headers});
        }

        // @ts-ignore
        if(carData.id !== parseInt(d.data.car.id)) {
          return json({
            error: 'Fahrzeug id stimmt nicht überein'
          }, {headers});
        }

        const rangeExists = await connectors['xxx'].query(`
          SELECT * FROM booking WHERE tsrange($1, $2, '()') && booking_range AND car_id = $3;
        `, 
        // @ts-ignore
        [new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.start_date)), new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.end_date)), 3]);
        
        console.log(carData);
        console.log(rangeExists);
        console.log(rangeExists.rows);
        if(rangeExists.rows.length > 0) {
          return json({
            error: 'Das Auto ist in diesem Zeitraum nicht mehr Verfügbar. Jemand war in diesem Augenblick eventuell schneller. Wir bitten um Verzeihung!'
          }, {headers});
        }
  
        const dates = getDatesBetween(new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.start_date)), new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.end_date)));
  
        const ordered: DATES_CALC_TYPE = getWeekDaysOrdered(dates as any) as unknown as DATES_CALC_TYPE; 
      
        const km_free_data: KM_FREE = {
          day_km_free: carData.day_km_free,
          day_weekend_km_free: carData.week_km_free,
          weekend_km_free: carData.weekend_km_free,
          week_km_free: carData.week_km_free,
          month_km_free: carData.month_km_free
        }

        const ek = d.data.booking_info?.extra_kilometer;

        if(ek) {
          const check = d.data.booking_info.extra_kilometer && !isNaN(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.extra_kilometer));
          if(check) {
            if(ek === '0') {
              kilometerPacket = 0;
            } else if(ek === '50') {
              kilometerPacket = 50;
            } else if(ek === '100') {
              kilometerPacket = 100;
            } else if(ek === '200') {
              kilometerPacket = 200;
            } else if(ek === '300') {
              kilometerPacket = 300;
            } else if(ek === '500') {
              kilometerPacket = 500;
            } else {
              kilometerPacket = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        
        const AMOUNT_PRICES: AMOUNT_KILOMETER_PRICE = {
          km: 0,
          km_50: kilometerPacket === 50 ? 1 : 0,
          km_100: kilometerPacket === 100 ? 1 : 0,
          km_200: kilometerPacket === 200 ? 1 : 0,
          km_300: kilometerPacket === 300 ? 1 : 0,
          km_500: kilometerPacket === 500 ? 1 : 0,
          coupon: 0,
          coupon_percent: 0
        };
  
        const priceKilometer: Omit<PriceKilometer_Type, 'id'> & { price_per_km: number; } = {
          km_50: carData.km_50,
          km_100: carData.km_100,
          km_200: carData.km_200,
          km_300: carData.km_300,
          km_500: carData.km_500,
          price_per_km: parseInt(carData.price_per_km)
        } 
  
        // @ts-ignore
        const sum = SumDates(ordered, {
          day: carData.day,
          day_weekend: carData.day_weekend,
          weekend: carData.weekend,
          week: carData.week,
          month: carData.month
        });
  
        const freeKM = CalcFreeKilometer(ordered, km_free_data);
  
        const priceKilometerOnly = calcPrices({
          priceKilometer,
          amountKilometer: AMOUNT_PRICES,
          clonePrice: 0
        });

        // check if email exists then get the id else create an client

        const clientRow = await getClientByEmail({db_name: 'xxx', email: d.data.info.email});
        let user_id = '';

        await client.query('BEGIN');

        if(clientRow.length > 0) {
          user_id = clientRow[0].id;
        } else {
          const clientAdd = await addClient({db_name: 'xxx', client: {
            id: '',
            salutation: 'HERR',
            surname: d.data.info.surname,
            lastname: d.data.info.lastname,
            company: d.data.info.company ?? '',
            address: d.data.info.street,
            plz: parseInt(d.data.info.plz) ?? 0,
            city: d.data.info.city,
            country: 'Deutschland',
            phone: d.data.info.phone,
            email: d.data.info.email,
            birthday: `${d.data.info.day}.${d.data.info.month}.${d.data.info.year}`,
            id_number: d.data.info.id_card_number ?? '',
            driver_license_number: d.data.info.driver_license_number ?? ''
          }});

          if(clientAdd.client?.id) {
            await client.query('ROLLBACK');
            return json({
              error: 'Client action not performed. Try again.'
            }, {headers});
          }
          user_id = clientAdd.client?.id ? clientAdd.client?.id.toString() : ''
        }

        // add client
  
        const endObj: ICreateProcess & { price_kilometer: number; paid?: string; } = {
          tk: '0',
          form: 'create_process',
          send_mail: '1',
          type: 'BOOKING',
          pick_up_station_id: stationData.station_id.toString(),
          return_station_id: stationData.station_id.toString(),
          date_from: new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.start_date)).toString(),
          date_to: new Date(parseInt(d.data.booking_info.end_date)).toString(),
          price: sum.toString(),
          car_id: carData.id.toString(),
          manual: '0',
          coupon: '0',
          coupon_percent: '0',
          km: '0',
          km_50: kilometerPacket === 50 ? '1' : '0',
          km_100: kilometerPacket === 100 ? '1' : '0',
          km_200: kilometerPacket === 200 ? '1' : '0',
          km_300: kilometerPacket === 300 ? '1' : '0',
          km_500: kilometerPacket === 500 ? '1' : '0',
          payment: '100% (Überweisung/Kreditkarte/Paypal)',
          paid: sum.toString(),
          business_id: '1',
          price_kilometer: priceKilometerOnly,
          free_km: freeKM.toString(),
          client_id: user_id?.toString(),
          extra_km: calcExtraKM(AMOUNT_PRICES).toString(),
          ordered,
          notice: ''
        }
  
        const id = await createProcess({db_name: 'xxx', p: endObj});
        console.log(id);
        if(typeof id === 'number') {
  
          const buffer = await getPDFVerify({db_name: 'xxx', id: id as number});

          const email = clientRow[0].email;
         
          if(typeof email === 'string' && endObj.send_mail === '1') {
            console.log('INNGGEST');
            console.log(email);
            const saaa = await inngest.send({
              name: 'Default ingest key',
              data: {
                email,
                // @ts-ignore
                buffer
              }
            });
            console.log('ERROR INNGEST');
            await client.query('ROLLBACK');
          }
        } else {
          await client.query('ROLLBACK');
          return json({error: 'Fehler beim erstellen der Buchung. Versuche es erneut.'}, {headers});
        }

        await client.query('COMMIT');

        const ps = await paypal.capturePayment(d.id);

        console.log('HI');

        if(ps?.status === 'COMPLETED') {
          return json(ps, {headers});
        } else {
          await client.query('ROLLBACK');
          return json({error: 'Fehler last'}, {headers});
        }

      } else {
        return json({error: 'Daten unvollständig.'}, {headers});
      }

    } else {
      return json({error: 'Daten fehlen.'}, {headers});
    }
```